# LINQ-to-SQL GroupBy across Many-to-Many Divide

Tags: linq-to-sql, group-by, many-to-many

I have the following issue to solve.

I have an IQueryable list of Invoices, each tied to an Account.  Each Account can have multiple Structures, and Accounts and Structures are tied together by a table called StructureAccount.  It looks like this:

Invoice ---> Account <-----StructureAccount ----> Structure

I want to query my IQueryable list of Invoices and group by Structure.StructureID or StructureAccount.StructureID.  But, because any given invoice can be tied to multiple Structures the best I can get is a LIST of StructureIDs, and therefore my GroupBy is not working.

I feel like I am missing an obvious solution to this.

I should note that I understand that the data in any one Invoice would be counted multiple times if the Invoice were tied to more than one Structure, and this is "solved" by a "PercentAllocationtoStructure" value in the table StructureAccount.

I hope I did a good enough job explaining this problem.  Let me know if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm...I might be missing something, but doesn't the following work?

```
var q = from i in Invoice
        join a in Account
        on i.AccountID equals a.AccountID
        join sa in StructureAccount
        on i.AccountID equals sa.AccountID
        join s in Structure
        on sa.StructureID equals s.StructureID
        group i by s.StructureID;
```

I tested it on the following dummy data:

```
var Invoice = new [] {
    new { InvoiceID = 1, AccountID = 1 },
    new { InvoiceID = 2, AccountID = 2 },
    new { InvoiceID = 3, AccountID = 3 },
    new { InvoiceID = 4, AccountID = 1 },
    new { InvoiceID = 5, AccountID = 2 },
    new { InvoiceID = 6, AccountID = 3 }
};

var Account = new [] {
    new { AccountID = 1 },
    new { AccountID = 2 },
    new { AccountID = 3 },
};

var StructureAccount = new [] {
    new { AccountID = 1, StructureID = 2 },
    new { AccountID = 1, StructureID = 3 },
    new { AccountID = 2, StructureID = 2 },
    new { AccountID = 3, StructureID = 1 },
    new { AccountID = 3, StructureID = 2 },
};

var Structure = new [] {
    new { StructureID = 1 },
    new { StructureID = 2 },
    new { StructureID = 3 }
};
```

And it returns:

```
StructureID = 2:
    InvoiceID's: 1,2,3,4,5,6

StructureID = 3:
    InvoiceID's: 1,4

StructureID = 1:
    InvoiceID's: 3,6
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you have the following starting point:

```
IQueryable<Invoice> _invoices;
```

First, you need to get a list of all the items that you will be iterating over:

```
IQueryable<Account> _accounts = _invoices.Select(myInvoice => myInvoice.Account).Distinct();
IQueryable<StructuredAccount> _structuredAccounts = _accounts.SelectMany(myAccount => myAccount.StructuredAccounts);
IQueryable<Structure> _structures = _structuredAccounts.Select(myStructuredAccount => myStructuredAccount.Structure).Distinct();
```

Next, you need to go back and join your `Structure` objects to the respective `Invoice` objects.

For this, you'll:

1. Get a set of `{Structure, Account}` pairs:

   var structureAccountJoin = _structures.Join(_structuredAccounts, _structure => structure.StructuredID, _structuredAccount => _structuredAccount.StructuredID, (structure, structuredAccount) => new { Structure = structure, Account = structuredAccount.Account });
2. Get a set of `{Structure, Invoice}` pairs:

   var structureInvoiceJoin = structureAccountJoin.Join(_invoices, myObj => myObj.Account.AccountID, invoice => invoice.AccountID, (myObj, invoice) => new { Structure = myObj.Structure, Invoice = invoice});

Finally, you can group everything by the `Structure` object:

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<Structure, Invoice>> groupByStructure = structureInvoiceJoin.GroupBy(obj => obj.Structure, result => result.Invoice);
```

(GroupBy documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx)

Now, you can access everything as follows:

```
foreach(IGrouping<Structure, Invoice> groupEntry in groupByStructure)
{
     Structure currentGrouping = groupEntry.Key;

     foreach(Invoice inv in groupEntry)
     {
           // do something;
     }
}
```

As a note, this is a very complex script that requires a lot of steps if you don't have access to the tables directly.  You may want to look into creating a StoredProcedure for this instead, as it will be more efficient and you'll be able to use SQL Joins instead. If you have only an `IQueryable<Invoice>` to work with and access to nothing else, there is probably a design problem somewhere in your architecture.

Nevertheless, this is the way to make it work based on your requirements, if I read them correctly.